# Best online resources for learning Java 6 from Java 4 background?

Tags: java

Our company is finally coming out of the dark ages and embracing Java 6.  We have been using Java 4 for many years and I'm interested in learning the new features offered by Java 5 and 6.  So, can anyone recommend any online resources to help me learn what's new since Java 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for generics, most everything there is to learn can be done incrementally.  Nothing in Java *requires* you do something the new way.  Start with enhanced-for, autoboxing, varargs and formatted printing.

With generics, read up on an overview, say [Angelika's FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html), and then begin applying generics bit by bit - be prepared to invest some time for the more complex generics programming.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the **New Features of JDK 1.5** from the [Java 5 & Java 6 Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/java5.html) (at coreservlets.com) for a quick overview:

> All the material in this section is
>   covered in more detail in earlier
>   sections. But, if you are a real
>   old-timer and only know Java 1.4 or
>   earlier (Gasp! How 20th century!),
>   this section might be useful for you.
>
> - [This tutorial section in PDF](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/java5/23-Java5-Features.pdf).
> - Topics covered:
>
>   - The for/each loop
>   - Scanner and command-line input
>   - Generics
>   - Autoboxing
>   - Varargs
>   - printf
>   - Reading command-line input

Also check the [Java Language Features](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html#lang) in the **New Features and Enhancements of J2SE 5.0**.

Answer (score 1):

I would read through these:
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/beta2.html

Answer (score 0):

The main changes to the language it self were introduced in the Java 5 release.

These include:

- generics
- enchanced for loops
- var args
- autoboxing

and a number of others

Here's an interesting article with examples:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/releases/j2se15/

Java 6 changes were most on performance and new APIs you should start with the changes in 5 first

Answer (score 0):

Just as a clarification, you mean that you currently use JDK 1.4.x right? I think Sun's marketing machine when from Java 1.0 Java 1.1 Java 2 ( 1.2 , 1.3, 1.4) to Java 5 (1.6) and finally Java 6 (1.6). I never heard of "Java 4" in the Sun literature. I agree that :
http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html give a nice summary from the horse's mouth